# Android SQLiteException unable to close due to unfinalised statements

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android app when I'm trying to query the database, everything works fine but sometimes I'm getting this exception, not always. I searched for this problem and found solutions that works for others but not for me.

I'm using this code in another thread in AsyncTask

```
Cursor data = db.rawQuery(sql.toString(), null);


    if (data != null && data.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.setId(data.getLong(0));
            acc.setName(data.getString(1));

            Price balance = new Price(0L, Price.theUnit);
            balance.setAmount(data.getString(2), Price.rial);
            acc.setBalance(balance);

            accounts.add(acc);

        } while (data.moveToNext());
    }

    data.close();
    dbHelper.close();
```

What is the problem?

Comment: In general you should place calls like `data.close()` and `dbHelper.close()` into a `finally {}` block, to ensure they are called even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Which line does the code crash? Can you provide the stack trace in logcat?